# Нужно ли загружать на сайт шрифты open-sans, sans-serif?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

будет выглядеть так
font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
Эти шрифты предустановлены в ОС, так что нужно ли их всё равно грузить через @font-face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не только этот, но и любой другой `@font-face` надо описывать так, чтобы он в начале искал шрифт в самой системе. Гугл-шрифты так и делают, кстати:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mxJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
```

А Open Sans, кстати, предустановлен не в любой ОС, потому да, его необходимо описывать в `@font-face`.

Comment: а как же sans-serif, его тоже через @font-face?

Comment: Sans-serif это не конкретный шрифт, это группа шрифтов без засечек. Соответственно, его вы не сможете загрузить никуда ).